# Microsoft office 2013 Reinstall

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-office, reinstall, microsoft-office-2013

I am trying to re install Office 2013, but it says:
"We found a pre-release or beta version of an office product on your computer and can't install because of it. Please uninstall any pre-release software using the programs and features item in your control panel and try installing again." The problem is it was already uninstalled.

Thank you to all who help.

Comment: Did you restart after you uninstalled?  If not, I would try a restart.

Comment: Another thought that comes to mind is to make sure that `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office` folder is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I would run the installer "fix it" from the Microsoft KB found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501).

This should remove any remains of the office product on your system.